# loading Dynamic data iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

im new to obj-c, and need help im trying to dynamically load data (10 thumbnails and one line of copy for each) onto the iphone. when one of the thumbnails is clicked it will open its own view, which will display additional text and have a back button.

i have a programming background in ActionScript and the way i'd set it up is have a mc in the library that would hold the thumbnail/copy. the mc would then get added to the stage 10times.

is there a way to do it like that with the iphone?

thanks any feed back would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you new to the English language as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely look at UITableView class http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1 and sample code ( TableView Suite ) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318
And then Navigation controller ( UINavigationController )

Comment: thanks MacDev, is there a way to set it up in a grid view?
img1     img1a
copy1    copy1a

img2     img2a
copy2    copy2a

essential img1,copy1 and img1a and copy1a would be in 1 "movieclip1" and img2,copy2 and img2a and copy2a would be in its own "movieclip2"

so i could adjust positioning "movieclip1".x = ... and so on

Comment: Checkout AQGridView http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/528737778/aqgridview-lives-for-my-ipad-dev-camp-hackathon  If you don't want to add third party lib to your app then I would say look at custom cell config in UITableView